# WP8 Geolocator and Cellular network

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

According to MSDN, different techniques (GPS, WIFI triangulation, cellular network) are used in windows phone 8 to get phone position. The only way, which I was able to find this far, was method, based on the Geolocator (fow WP7 GeoCoordinateWatcher) usage. So, the question is: Does Geolocator use all these techniques to locate phone position, or it uses only GPS data?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431814%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Although the Location Service uses multiple sources of location information, and any of the sources may not be available at any given time (for example, no GPS satellites or cell phone towers may be accessible), **the native code layer handles the work of evaluating the available data and choosing the best set of sources.**

So it seems like you can't control which source is used but rather the available source will be used based on the specified position accuracy on GeoCoordinateWatcher.

Comment: The corollary to this is that if you want to use a specific technique, you'll have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is this: it uses all of these sources. I do not know which one is the most important, but it seems they're all pretty much equally accurate (unless you look really closely).

For interest's sake, the GPS service is most suited to navigation apps which will take you outdoors and away from dense concentrations of wifi hotspots and cellular towers.

Wifi triangulation is great for when you need to be indoors.

Cellular triangulation seems to me to be a fall-back option for when wifi isn't enabled on your phone or there aren't enough known wifi hotspots to use in the calculation.

So, to sum up I would imagine that the software decides, based on relative signal strength and the resultant accuracy, which method to use to calculate your position.